# How to rereduce with Mongoid to aggrerate data from two distinct fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

## The context

Two documents of a mongodb mapped on rails/mongoid classes. The two class are `Task` and `Subscription`. For performance reasons, `Subscription.current_task` stores a `Task::CurrentTask` which is contains a subset of attributes of a `Task`, but the real current task matching a subscription is the one with the highest `Task#pos` for a given `Task#subscription_id`.

## The problem

Some inconsistencies appeared between some attributes from the `Subscription.current_task` and the should be matching `Task`, notably the `state` field.

## Goal

Listing all current tasks from `Subscription`s which doesn't match the last Task for this subscription.

## Solution aimed

First, map/reduce `Task` to get the last one for each subscription and storing that into a temporary collection. Thirdly rereduce with this temporary collection on `Subscription` to obtains for each subscription an object containing both the actual last task and the current embeded subset copy. Thirdly, create the report for elements where actual and copied task mismatch.

## Difficulty encountered

While having read the [official mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/) and [mangoid documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-mtd), and other example in misc. blog like [MongoDB Map Re-Reduce and joins – performance tuning](https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2013/03/29/mongodb-map-re-reduce-joins-performance-tuning/) and [MongoDB, Mongoid, MapReduce and Embedded Documents.](https://blog.many-monkeys.com/mongo_db_mongoid_map_reduce_and_embedded_documents_/), I'm still unable to come with a working solution for the rereduce step.

## The nonfunctional solution wrote so far:

```
# map/reduce of tasks to get the last one of each subscripton
last_task_map = %Q{
  function() {
    var key = this.subscription_id;
    var value = {
        task: {
          pos: this.pos,
          task_id: this._id,
          state: this.state
        },
        current_task: null
    };
    emit(key, value);
  }
}
last_task_reduce = %Q{
  function(key, tasks) {
    var last_task = tasks[0];
    for ( var i=1; i < tasks.length; i++ ) {
      if(tasks[i].pos > last_task.pos) {
        last_task = tasks[i];
      }
    }
    
    var value = {
      task: {pos: last_task.pos, task_id: last_task.task_id, state: last_task.state},
      current_task: null
    };
    return value;
  }
}

# map/reduce of `current_task`s to merged with previous results
subscription_map = %Q{
  function() {
    if(!this.current_task) {
      return;
    }
    var key = this._id;
    var value = {
      task: null,
      current_task: {
        pos: this.current_task.pos,
        task_id: this.current_task.task_id,
        state: this.current_task.state,
        source: 'current_task',
      }
    };
    emit(key, value);
  };
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, tasks) {
    if(tasks[0].current_task == nill) {
      return {task: tasks[0].task, current_task: tasks[1].current_task};
    }
    return {task: tasks[1].task, current_task: tasks[0].current_task};
  }
}


buffer = 'current_task_consistency'
# temporary collection seems unremoved when serially calling the script with 
# `load` in a `rails c` prompt, so we drop it to avoid unwanted glitch merge
Mongoid.default_client[buffer].drop
t = Task.map_reduce(last_task_map, last_task_reduce).out(replace: buffer)
s = Subscription.map_reduce(subscription_map, reduce).out(reduce: buffer)
t.each{ |e| puts e } # ok: `{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592dd603e138236671587b04'), "value"=>{"task"=>{"pos"=>0.0, "task_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592dd604e138236671587b0f'), "state"=>40.0}, "current_task"=>nil}}`
puts t.counts # ok: {"input"=>83900, "emit"=>83900, "reduce"=>36115, "output"=>28625}
s.each{ |e| puts e } # ko: {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592dd603e138236671587b04'), "value"=>{"task"=>nil, "current_task"=>{"pos"=>0.0, "task_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('592dd604e138236671587b0f'), "state"=>40.0, "source"=>"current_task"}}}
puts s.counts # ko: {"input"=>28632, "emit"=>28624, "reduce"=>0, "output"=>28624}
```

The expected result for the second map/reduce is a merge of the `current_task_consistency` and the `subscription_map` results which should all pass within the reduce, when none is performed according to `counts`, and indeed the output from `s` elements reveals that no `task` key was assigned with the `current_task_consistency` value.

## Questions related to the exposed problem

- What does the implementation lakes?
- As far as I understand, this solution do provide `merge` functions which are idempotent and which provides output consistent with the corresponding `match` function returns. What do I may misunderstand about how the `out` parameter works and how the rereduce input/output should be managed?

## Additional remarks

The third step, to generate the report, is intended to be implemented as a `finalize` function applied on the second map/reduce. But maybe a third map/reduce might be a better way, or not. As a whole the implementation might be badly poorly structured at least from a performance point of view, and feed back is welcome on that point too.

Comment: If I understand correctly then first you get data from `Task` which is grouped on `subscription_id` returning the matching data for "largest" value from "pos". Then you want to go through the subscriptions and marry up some data to the results of the first output? Is any data from "subscriptions" going to be returned for keys that would not be produced from the "tasks" output? Because where there would be no new keys, then you probably should be using aggregate and `$lookup` instead of doing a two stage mapReduce.

Comment: It seems that you did well understood the goal, and I wasn't aware of the `$lookup` possibility. I will investigate that once I finished with the map/reduce/finalize solution, as for me it's also a good exercise to discover how to query such a thing in Mongo. Thank you.

Comment: see [aggregation documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [$lookup documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first problem of the proposed solution was simply a ruby/js syntax mix up, `nill` instead of `null`. Unfortunately the script was failing silently, at least in the pry console where I was running `load current_task_consistency.rb`.

Here is a working solution, with two map/reduce and a query on the resulting temporary collection.

```
# map/reduce of tasks to get the last one of each subscripton
last_task_map = %Q{
  function() {
    var key = this.subscription_id;
    var value = {
        task: {
          pos: this.pos,
          task_id: this._id,
          state: this.state
        },
        current_task: null
    };
    emit(key, value);
  }
}
last_task_reduce = %Q{
  function(key, tasks) {
    var last_task = tasks[0];
    for ( var i=1; i < tasks.length; i++ ) {
      if(tasks[i].pos > last_task.pos) {
        last_task = tasks[i];
      }
    }

    var value = {
      task: {pos: last_task.pos, task_id: last_task.task_id, state: last_task.state},
      current_task: null
    };
    return value;
  }
}

# map/reduce of `current_task`s merged side by side with the corresponding
# subscription last task 
subscription_map = %Q{
  function() {
    if(!this.current_task) {
      return;
    }
    var key = this._id;
    var value = {
      task: null,
      current_task: {
        pos: this.current_task.pos,
        task_id: this.current_task.task_id,
        state: this.current_task.state,
      }
    };
    emit(key, value);
  };
}

subscription_reduce = %Q{
  function(key, tasks) {
    if(tasks[0].current_task == null) {
      return {task: tasks[0].task, current_task: tasks[1].current_task};
    }
    return {task: tasks[1].task, current_task: tasks[0].current_task};
  }
}

buffer = 'current_task_consistency'
# temporary collection seems unremoved when serially calling the script with 
# `load` in a `rails c` prompt, so we drop it to avoid unwanted merge glitch
Mongoid.default_client[buffer].drop

Task.map_reduce(last_task_map, last_task_reduce).
  out(replace: buffer).
  execute

Subscription.
  map_reduce(subscription_map, subscription_reduce).
  out(reduce: buffer).
  execute

ascertain_inconsistency = %Q{
  this.value.current_task == null ||
    this.value.current_task.state != this.value.task.state
}

inconsistencies = Mongoid.default_client['current_task_consistency'].
  find( { "$where": ascertain_inconsistency } )
```